# I can't get Tweet Replies from database on my .NET 7.0 Web API

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I am making a Twitter Clone API. When I try to get a Tweet by Id with its replies, it returns null even if there is a reply.
Tweet.cs

```cs
using TwitterCloneApp.Core.Interfaces;

namespace TwitterCloneApp.Core.Models
{
    public class Tweet : IBaseEntity, IDeletable, IUpdatedAt, ICreatedAt
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
        public bool isMainTweet { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; } = false;
        public DateTime? DeletedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Tag>? Tags { get; set; } // Many-to-Many ilişkisi için koleksiyon
        public ICollection<Tweet>? Replies { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Like>? Likes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

TwReply.Cs (for relation)

```cs
namespace TwitterCloneApp.Core.Models
{
    public class TwReply
    {
        public int TweetId { get; set; }
        public int ReplyId { get; set; }
        public Tweet Tweet { get; set; }
        public Tweet Reply { get; set; }
    }
}
```

TweetDto.cs

```cs
using TwitterCloneApp.DTO.Tag;
using TwitterCloneApp.DTO.User;

namespace TwitterCloneApp.DTO.Tweet
{
    public class TweetDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public UserResponseDto User { get; set; }
        public string? Content { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public int LikeCount { get; set; }
        public List<TagResponseDto>? Tags { get; set; }
        public List<ReplyResponseDto>? Replies { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ReplyResponseDto.cs

```cs
using TwitterCloneApp.DTO.User;

namespace TwitterCloneApp.DTO.Tweet
{
    public class ReplyResponseDto
    {
        public UserResponseDto User { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public int LikeCount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

UserResponseDto.cs

```cs
namespace TwitterCloneApp.DTO.User
{
    public class UserResponseDto
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string? ProfileImg { get; set; }
    }
}
```

TweetController part

```cs
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTweetByIdAsync(int id)
{
    var tweet = await _tweetService.GetTweetByIdAsync(id);
    return Ok(tweet);
}
```

TweetService part

```cs
public async Task<TweetDto> GetTweetByIdAsync(int tweetId)
{
    return await _tweetRepository.GetTweetWithTagsByIdAsync(tweetId);
}
```

TweetRepository part

```cs
public async Task<TweetDto> GetTweetWithTagsByIdAsync(int tweetId)
{
    var tweet = await _tweet.Include(t => t.Tags)
                            .Include(t => t.Replies).ThenInclude(reply => reply.User)
                            .Include(t => t.User)
                            .Include(t => t.Likes)
                            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == tweetId);

    if (tweet == null)
    {
        return null; // veya gerekli işlemleri yapın
    }

    var tweetDto = new TweetDto
    {
        Id = tweet.Id,
        Content = tweet.Content,
        CreatedAt = tweet.CreatedAt,
        LikeCount = tweet.Likes?.Count ?? 0,
        Tags = tweet.Tags?.Select(t => new TagResponseDto
        {
            Name = t.Name
        }).ToList(),
        User = new UserResponseDto
        {
            UserName = tweet.User.UserName,
            DisplayName = tweet.User.DisplayName,
            ProfileImg = tweet.User.ProfileImg
        },
        Replies = tweet.Replies?.Select(reply => new ReplyResponseDto
        {
            User = new UserResponseDto
            {
                UserName = reply.User.UserName,
                DisplayName = reply.User.DisplayName,
                ProfileImg = reply.User.ProfileImg
            },
            Content = reply.Content,
            CreatedAt = reply.CreatedAt,
            LikeCount = reply.Likes?.Count ?? 0
        }).ToList()
    };

    return tweetDto;
}
```

AppDbContext.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Reflection;
using TwitterCloneApp.Core.Models;

namespace TwitterCloneApp.Repository
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        { 
        }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Tweet> Tweets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Like> Likes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TwReply> TwReplies { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            
            var relationships = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                .SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys());

            foreach (var relationship in relationships)
            {
                relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
            }
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

    }
}
```

There are 2 replies (3 and 10) for Tweet Id:1
but output is:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "user": {
    "userName": "asdasdasd",
    "displayName": "asdasdasd",
    "profileImg": "string"
  },
  "content": "First tweet",
  "createdAt": null,
  "likeCount": 3,
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "#testingSeed1"
    },
    {
      "name": "#testingSeed2"
    },
    {
      "name": "#testing"
    }
  ],
  "replies": []
}
```

[image: Database Replies Table]

[image: Database Tweet Table]

I tried to get replies while getting a Tweet by Id but the program doesn't get Replies. I checked how does it work with breakpoints and it seems problem is in `TweetRepository` part. It returns nothing for Replies when it gets entity. I use Entity Framework Core BTW.

Comment: Can you show the DbContext class?

Comment: Is the Tweet you are testing with replied to?

Comment: @LajosArpad yes sir 3 and 10 id tweets are replies for id 1

Comment: Id 1 is a reply to itself?

Comment: How are your tables looking alike in your database?

Comment: @vernou I added a picture there was a mistake in comment

Comment: @LajosArpad I added a picture there was a mistake in comment

Comment: @LajosArpad I also added Tweets Table you need more?

Comment: In the Replies table are TweetId and ReplyId foreign keys?

Comment: @LajosArpad I already said I use EF Core. Doesn't it automatically define relations? Cause it did for Follows and TagTweet relations. I wrote my TwReply.cs and Tweet.cs entities to show my relations and wrote I use EF Core so this looks like an unnecessary question : )

Comment: @OnatEgeKaraman if you know what question is necessary and what question is unnecessary, then how come that you ended up needing help here?

Comment: @LajosArpad I just asked if EF Core doesn't do the relations.. Also checked my database. Replies related to Tweets and Foreign kekys are TweetId and ReplyId both referenced to Tweet.Id

Answer (score 1):

The entity `Tweet` (simplified) is :

```cs
public class Tweet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; } = "";
    public ICollection<Tweet>? Replies { get; set; }
}
```

Then EF Core will tanlaste this model to this DB Schema :

```sql
CREATE TABLE [Tweets] (
    [Id] int NOT NULL,
    [Content] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
    [TweetId] int NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Tweets] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Tweets_Tweets_TweetId] FOREIGN KEY ([TweetId]) REFERENCES [Tweets] ([Id])
);
```

When the DB schema isn't specified, EF Core use convention to determine the DB schema. And the convention for a collection navigation property to the same entity is 1 to n (a tweet can have manyreplies, but can reply to only one tweet). It's like the model was :

```cs
public class Tweet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; } = "";
    public ICollection<Tweet>? Replies { get; set; }
    public Tweet ReplyTo { get; set; }
}
```

You can refer to the documentatino [EF Core : Conventions for relationship discovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/conventions) for more information about the convention about relationship.

---

In you case, it's a relation n to n (a tweet can have many reply and can reply to many tweet) by the intermediate entity TwReply.

By convention, the model will be :

```cs
public class Tweet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; } = "";
    public ICollection<TwReply>? Replies { get; set; }
}

public class TwReply
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Tweet Tweet { get; set; }
    public Tweet Reply { get; set; }
}
```

If you want keep your model, you need to specify manually the relation like :

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ...
    modelBuilder.Entity<Tweet>()
        .HasMany(t => t.Replies)
        .WithMany()
        .UsingEntity<TwReply>(
            i => i.HasOne(tr => tr.Reply).WithMany(),
            i => i.HasOne(tr => tr.Tweet).WithMany()
        );
}
```

Comment: I changed my entities and created a new initial migration still replies doesnt seem.

Comment: @OnatEgeKaraman, My bad, I inverted the relation order in `UsingEntity`. It's fixed

Comment: Actually this is a good solution but I added another entity as Reply and created a relationship between Tweet. It's better for now. Thanks :)